# Eliminating white space without altering text area

Tags: margins, pdf

Suppose that I produce a document using the article class. What I want to do is trim the white space around the text area without changing the text itself. I tried \pdfpageheight. It's sort of the right idea, but this will cut off text. Ideally, I would like to be able to specify something like "add 1/4in of margin about the text." The line breaks and page breaks should be left untouched.

Comment: Are you speaking of a single page of content?  If so, you can possibly use the `standalone` class.

Comment: The content may span several pages.

Comment: But not the whole document?  You will also need to reduce \paperheight and \topmargin (negative is fine, so long as it is greater than -1in).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  In the text of the question, you say "with changing the text".  That should be "without changing".  Please fix.  (I don't want my name to appear in the index as modifying the entry; it's your question, not mine, and even a new contributor can edit their own question.)

Comment: Are you talking about what you see on the screen or the physical printed pages? If the latter then try the `crop` package and physically trim the printed pages. Otherwise try the `geometry` package to reduce LaTeX's understanding of the paper size.